# MobSF: Solve @rpath violation

Tags: ios, security, rpath

We tested one of our iOS app with MobSF and the report highlighted that the binary has Runpath Search Path (@rpath) set.
In certain cases an attacker can abuse this feature to run arbitrary executable for code execution and privilege escalation.

I ran `otool -L` against the binary to check which dependencies are concerned. It turns out that all pods (Cocaopod) and and some system libraries are concerned.

```
name @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire (offset 24)
name @rpath/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib (offset 24)
name @rpath/libswiftCoreData.dylib (offset 24)
name @rpath/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib (offset 24)
```

I wonder how to fix this issue. Cocoapods prints a warning if the project build setting `Runpath Search Paths` does not include $(inherited).

Is using @rpath considered harmful?
Any help/information appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The **Runpath Search Path** instructs the dynamic linker to search for a dynamic library (dylib) on an ordered list of paths, sort of like how Unix looks for binaries on $PATH.

If your application uses the ***Swift Package Manager***, in order to compile the libraries without rpath you need to use some hidden build flags. On your local command line run:

[image]

Note the swift compiler option no-stdlib-rpath which disables rpath entries during compilation.
Configure your build settings so that the application is built with this configuration flag, **e.g.: swift build -c release -Xswiftc -no-toolchain-stdlib-rpath.**

Alternatively, if your application uses **Cocoapods**, you can first check the install directory of the pods:

[image]

And then use the following configuration on your Podfile:
[image]

For reference - [MobSF IPA Binary Analysis](https://inesmartins.github.io/mobsf-ipa-binary-analysis-step-by-step/index.html)